# Hindu customs to make a normal women to widow

Tags: customs

Why the women chew jeera & salt while seeing widow first time in their relatives ? If they don't chew, what will happen ?

Comment: Married Hindu women can not be made widows by some customs. Possible only if their husband's dies. Your question is unclear in it's current form. Can you make it clearer? BTW welcome to the site :)

Comment: I don't understand the question in the title. Are you asking if there is a formal procedure by which a married woman turns into a widow? Then the question in the body seems unrelated to what you are asking in the title. It should be asked as a separate question.